How to Display website name on google search engine with Nginx , Next.js 14 Application Correctly?
I am setting up a Next.js 14 application with Nginx as the reverse proxy server. I want to make sure my website is properly displayed under the name AI Flavoured. like my website name is appearing as aiflavoured.com which i want as Ai Flavoured. Here are some details about my current setup:

Current Setup

Next.js Application:

I have the following Next.js component setup with metadata that should display my website's name as "AI Flavoured":
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
import { Footer } from "@/components/footer";
import { Header } from "@/components/header/header";
import Image from "next/image";
import CSS from "./flavours.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import { ChatGPTIconGlow, StableDiffusionIcon } from "@/components/logo";
import { getUserSession } from "@/actions/userSession";

const website = process.env.WEBSITE_URL || 'https://aiflavoured.com';

export const metadata = {
  title: "AI Flavoured | AI Image Generation, AI Presentations, AI Audio Creation, and AI PDF Summarization AI Chat with doc",
  metadataBase: new URL(`${website}/flavours`),
  description: "Experience the best in AI with our comprehensive solutions. Generate stunning images with DALL-E and SDXL, create professional presentations, transform text into high-quality audio, and summarize PDFs. Enhance your productivity with our AI tools.",
  applicationName: "AI Flavoured",
  authors: [
    {
      name: "Sourabh",
      url: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/sourabh-sharma-8987451a2/",
    },
  ],
  name: 'AI Flavoured',
  generator: "AI Flavoured",
  keywords: [
    "AI", "AI Flavoured", "AI Image", "ChatGPT", "DALL-E", "Stable Diffusion XL",
    "AI Audio", "PDF Summarization", "GPT", "Chat", "AI Presentation",
    "PPT AI", "PowerPoint AI", "AI Presentation Maker", "SDXL Base",
    "SDXL", "DALL-E", "Chat with Doc", "AI Chat", "ChatGPT-4o", "ChatGPT-4",
    "ChatGPT-3", "GPT"
  ],
  referrer: "origin",
  creator: "Sourabh",
  publisher: "AI Flavoured",
  robots: {
    index: true,
    follow: true,
  },
  alternates: { canonical: "/" },
  openGraph: {
    title: "AI Flavoured | AI Image Generation, AI Presentations, AI Audio Creation, and AI PDF Summarization AI Chat with doc",
    description: "Experience the best in AI with our comprehensive solutions. Generate stunning images with DALL-E and SDXL, create professional presentations, transform text into high-quality audio, and summarize PDFs. Enhance your productivity with our AI tools.",
    url: `${website}/flavours`,
    type: "website",
    locale: "en_IN",
    site_name: "AI Flavoured - Flavours",
  }
};

Nginx Configuration:
Here's my current Nginx configuration for the Next.js application:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name aiflavoured.com www.aiflavoured.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
    listen 80;
    server_name aiflavoured.com www.aiflavoured.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name aiflavoured.com www.aiflavoured.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/key.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}


Issues and Questions:
-Website Name Not Displaying Correctly:
Although I set the website name as "AI Flavoured" in the Next.js metadata, it doesn't seem to be displaying correctly when I visit the site. Could this be an issue with my Nginx setup or Next.js configuration?
Are there any best practices I should follow to ensure that the website's title and metadata are displayed correctly across different browsers and devices?
How can I ensure SEO optimizations are correctly applied with Nginx and Next.js?
Security:
Is my current Nginx configuration secure for production? What improvements can I make?
Nginx and Next.js Integration:
Are there any specific settings or modules I need to enable in Nginx to handle Next.js 14 features properly, such as ISR (Incremental Static Regeneration)?
Additional Information:
Hosting Provider: [Azure], Virtual Server
Deployment Method: [PM2]

Any help or pointers on configuring Nginx to work seamlessly with Next.js 14 would be greatly     appreciated!

Hi Piercing_wind, Is your issue resolved?

hello, meta data is correctly displaying, and i have refreshed the nginx server properly, but on google its still showing my domain as website name i have requested reindexing of the website and lets see what happen after that.

Firstly, clear the cache. clearing cache help to resolve issues where changes to the site (like metadata updates) are not reflected in the browser.

combine the HTTP and HTTPS server blocks to ensure that all traffic is redirected properly.

Nginx Configuration:
# Redirect traffic from the server's private IP to the real domain
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.static.privatedns.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://aiflavoured.com$1 permanent;
}

# Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name aiflavoured.com www.aiflavoured.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Serve HTTPS traffic
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name aiflavoured.com www.aiflavoured.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/key.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /_next/static/ {
        alias /path/to/next/static/;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, immutable";
    }
}


I should follow to ensure that the website's title and metadata are displayed correctly across different browsers and devices?


Next.js metadata setup looks correct, but once confirm that it's applied consistently across all pages where you want the name "AI Flavoured" to appear. Referred this doc for SEO in Next.js 14 with Metadata API.

// pages/_app.js
import { metadata } from './path-to-your-metadata-file'; // Adjust path accordingly
import Head from 'next/head';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{metadata.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={metadata.description} />
        <meta property="og:title" content={metadata.openGraph.title} />
        <meta property="og:description" content={metadata.openGraph.description} />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content={metadata.openGraph.site_name} />
        {/* Add other meta tags as needed */}
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;

